# C++/CLI cannot access native member from different assembly

Tags: c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI dll where I have the source code but I cannot modify it and I have my own dll where I want to access a member variable:

Assembly 1 (cannot be modified):

```
public ref class A
{
public:
    int m_iInteger;
    SomeClass* m_pPointer;
};
```

Assembly 2 (own):

```
A^ a;
int i = a->m_iInteger; // no problem
SomeClass* x = a->m_pPointer;  // C2248
```

The Problem is that the compiler shows an error:

**error C2248: 'A::m_pPointer' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'**

The "Object Browser" shows:

**public SomeClass* m_pPointer Member of A**

Is there any way to access an native public member from a different assembly?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012

**Edit:**
class "SomeClass" is defined in a native dll (which I cannot modify too)

**Edit 2:**
I have found a Solution. Its not very nice but it works:

```
System::Reflection::Pointer^ ptr = (System::Reflection::Pointer^)typeof(A)->GetField("m_pPointer")->GetValue(a);
SomeClass* result = static_cast<SomeClass*>(System::Reflection::Pointer::Unbox(ptr));
```

Comment: This sample compiles fine for me. I can't help but think there is some additional code causing this. Also, you will get a Null Exception if you don't A^ a = gcnew A();.

Comment: Of course there is more code. It's a big Project. I've tried to simplify the code but I don't know which other code causes the error. I cannot access any native pointer from that managed class. Do you have any idea?

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbce2bh(v=vs.80).aspx) Is the documentation for that compiler error.  It rather sounds like a subclass or friend class gone wrong.

Comment: I've found two solutions for this error but I cannot use one of them because I cannot modify the native dll and the Assembly 1:
1: in the native dll "SomeClass" should be declared as public class SomeClass {};
2: in the Assembly 1 before the declaration of "A" there should be #pragma make_public(SomeClass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All native types are private by default (in terms of managed accessibility outside the assembly).  So, even though it is listed as public, since the type `SomeClass` is private, it makes it inaccessible. You can change this by prefixing the the `SomeClass` definition with `public` (if you can modify the `SomeClass` source code).  Or, if you can't modify the `SomeClass` source code, but you can modify code within that dll, you can use the pragma:

```
#pragma make_public(SomeClass)
```

That said, based on your description it sounds like you cannot modify Assembly1 at all, in which case you are out of luck.

Comment: I have tried #pragma make_public(SomeClass) with no result and I have tried #pragma make_public(A) with result:
error C2158: 'A' : #pragma make_public directive is currently supported for native non-template types only
Note: I've edited the Question